# Split text and digits by delimiter using regexp splitpart

Tags: sql, postgresql

From the table below

```
customer_id     config_json
a5  {"required_capacity": true, "setup_wizard_completed": true, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
b16 {"required_capacity": null, "setup_wizard_completed": true, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
        {"required_capacity": true, "cancelation_time_minutes": 0, "display_no_preference_in_booking": true}
```

I would like to split the config_json column into 2 columns as below

```
customer_id     name                   value
a5             required_capacity       true
a5             setup_wizard_completed  true 
...
b16            required_capacity       null
```

The regex part of the code currently looks like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(split_part(mp.config_json,', ',s.id),'[{}": ]|(true|false||null)','')
```

However, there are some remains such as below:

```
customer_id  name                          value
a5          cancelation_time_minutes0 
b16         custom_sender_idadsd
```

Thus, the formula above still needs to split by not just true,false or null, but also by digits or string.
How can I fix that part of the code?

Comment: If the contents of `config_json` is guaranteed to be valid json, why not use the json function?

Comment: i want to keep the expected table format for visualization purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_each()`:

```
select t.customer_id, config.key as name, config.value
from t cross join lateral
     json_each(t.config_json::json) config;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8d4d5bcf4f08dac3f2028d8763a7fe26) is a db<>fiddle.